# How to understand the `preprocess_input` function in keras for each model?

Tags: python, keras, python-decorators

I am trying to understand how the `preprocess_input` function works in keras for different models. I looked into the source code (i.e. [ResNet50](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/resnet50.py)) but could not make sense of the decorator `@keras_modules_injection` which is defined [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/__init__.py).

How does module injection work with decorators?

How can I directly see which preprocessings steps are performed for each model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the pre-trained models and their relevant codes were factored out a while ago into their own separate package called [`keras_applications`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications). Therefore, you can see the pre-processing logic, specifically the `preprocess_input` function [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/8a1e4d427999c26d1a1988dda45454769c4372a5/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L157).